# sklearn.metrics r2_score negative

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I can't understand `r2_score` in sklearn.metrics, which seems to return meaningless values. I followed all the "similar questions" proposed by stackoverflow (some of which elude to wrong argument sequence, which is why I include both orders below), but I'm still lost:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

data = [[0.70940504,0.81604095],
        [0.69506565,0.78922145],
        [0.66527803,0.72174502],
        [0.75251691,0.74893098],
        [0.72517034,0.73999503],
        [0.68269306,0.72230534],
        [0.75251691,0.77163700],
        [0.78954422,0.81163350],
        [0.83077994,0.94561242],
        [0.74107290,0.75122162]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
x  = df[0].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
y  = df[1].to_numpy()
print("r2               = ", r2_score(y, x))
print("r2 (wrong order) = ", r2_score(x, y))

lreg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lreg.fit(x, y)
y_pred = lreg.predict(x)
print("predicted values: ", y_pred)
print("slope           = ", lreg.coef_)
print("intercept       = ", lreg.intercept_)
print("score           = ", lreg.score(x, y))
```

returns

```
r2               =  0.01488309898850404  # surprise!!
r2 (wrong order) =  -0.7313385423077101  # even more of a surprise!!

predicted values:  [0.75664194 0.74219177 0.71217403 0.80008687 0.77252903 0.7297236 0.80008687 0.83740023 0.87895451 0.78855445]
slope           =  [1.00772544]
intercept       =  0.04175643677503682
score           =  0.5778168671193278
```

Plotting data and predicted values in Excel show that the `linear_model` return values make sense (orange dots fall on Excel trend line), but `r2_score` return values do not (in both argument sequences):

[image: linear regression fit with Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Your model explains nearly 60% of the target variance, which is much better than the average predictor (which would explain 0).

Why does your single feature explain less? Mainly because of the intercept in this case: `r2_score(y, x + 0.042)` would work nearly as good.

In a simplified way, you may think of R2 as `1 - (mean_squared_error(y, y_pred) / y.var())`. Not being centered around the target mean inflates the sum of squared residuals inevitably, resulting in a poor R2.